# Compact way to produce a large sequence of strings in lexical order

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I want to generate a sequence of strings with the following properties:

1. Lexically ordered
2. Theoretically infinite
3. Compact over a realistic range
4. Generated by a simple process of incrementation
5. Matches the regexp `/\w+/`

The obvious way to generate a lexically-ordered sequence is to choose a string length and pad the strings with a base value like this: `000000`, `000001`, etc. This approach poses a trade-off between the number of permutations and compactness: a string long enough to yield many permutations will be filled many zeros along the way. Plus, the length I choose sets an upper bound on the total number of permutations unless I have some mechanism for expanding the string when it maxes out.

So I came up with a sequence that works like this:

1. Each string consists of a "head", which is a base-36 number, followed by an underscore, and then the "tail", which is also a base-36 number padded by an increasing number of zeros
2. The first cycle goes from `0_0` to `0_z`
3. The second cycle goes from `1_00` to `1_zz`
4. The third cycle goes from `2_000` to `2_zzz`, and so on
5. Once the head has reached `z` and the tail consists of 36 `z`s, the first "supercycle" has ended. Now the whole sequence starts over, except the `z` remains at the beginning, so the new cycle starts with `z0_0`, then continues to `z1_00`, and so on
6. The second supercycle goes `zz0_0`, `zz1_00`, and so on

Although the string of `z`s in the head could become unwieldy over the long run, a single supercycle contains over 10^56 permutations, which is far more than I ever expect to use.  The sequence is theoretically infinite but very compact within a realistic range. For instance, the trillionth permutation is a succinct `7_bqd55h8s`.

I can generate the sequence relatively simply with this javascript function:

```js
function genStr (n) {
  n = BigInt(n);
  let prefix = "",
      cycle = 0n,
      max = 36n ** (cycle + 1n);
  while (n >= max) {
    n -= max;
    if (cycle === 35n) {
      prefix += "z";
      cycle = 0n;
    } else {
      cycle++;
    }
    max = 36n ** (cycle + 1n);
  }
  return prefix
         + cycle.toString(36)
         + "_"
         + n.toString(36).padStart(Number(cycle) + 1, 0);
}
```

The `n` parameter is a number that I increment and pass to the function to get the next member of the sequence. All I need to keep track of is a simple integer, making the sequence very easy to use.

So obviously I spent a lot of time on this and I think it's pretty good, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Is there a good algorithm for generating a sequence along the lines of the one I'm looking for?

Comment: An obvious improvement is to use uppercase letters too, since `\w` matches those, and you didn't say they have to be case-insensitive.

Comment: I thought about that, but my algorithm uses `toString(radix)` to generate the base-36 number, and the output is always lowercase. To go through and manipulate individual digits would add more complexity to the algorithm than I want. However, it occurs to me that I can uppercase the whole string (or even the head and tail separately) on one go-round, then start the cycle over and leave it lowercase. This will increase the total number of permutations in a cycle without adding a lot of complexity. Thanks!

Comment: Would a [compact trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A close idea to yours. (more rafined than my first edit...).

Let our alphabet be `A = {0,1,2,3}`.

Let `|2|` mean we iterate from 0 to 2 and `|2|^2` mean we generate the cartesian product in a lexically sorted manner `(00,01,10,11)`.

We start with

```
0 |3|
```

So we have a string of length 2. We "unshift" the digit 1 which "factorizes" since any `0|3|...` is less than `1|3|^2`.

```
1 |3|^2
```

Same idea: unshift 2, and make words of length 4.

```
2 |3|^3
```

Now we can continue and generate

```
3 |2| |3|^3
```

Notice `|2|` and not `|3|`. Now our maximum number becomes `32333`. And as you did, we can now add the carry and start a new supercycle:

```
33 0|3|
```

This is a slight improvement, since `_` can now be part of our alphabet: we don't need to reserve it as a token separator.

In our case we can represent in a supercycle:

```
n + n^2 + ... + n^(n-1) + (n-1) * n^(n-1)
\-----------------------/\--------------/
  geometric                special
```

In your case, the special part would be `n^n` (with the nuance that you have theorically one char less so replace `n` with `n-1` everywhere)

The proposed supercycle is of length :

```
P = (n \sum_{k = 0}^{n-2} n^k) + (n-1) * n^(n-1) 
P = (n \sum_{k = 0}^{n-3} n^k) + n^n
P = n(n^{n-2} - 1)/(n-1) + n^n
```

Here is an example diff with alphabet A={0,1,2}

```
my  genStr(grandinero)
,00 0_0                 
,01 0_1                 
,02 0_2                 
,100 1_00               
,101 1_01               
,102 1_02               
,110 1_10               
,111 1_11               
,112 1_12               
,120 1_20               
,121 1_21               
,122 1_22               
,2000 2_000     
,2001 2_001     
,2002 2_002     
,2010 2_010     
,2011 2_011     
,2012 2_012     
,2020 2_020     
,2021 2_021     
,2022 2_022     
,2100 2_100     
,2101 2_101     
,2102 2_102     
,2110 2_110     
,2111 2_111     
,2112 2_112     
,2120 2_120     
,2121 2_121     
,2122 2_122     
22,00 2_200 <-- end of my supercycle if no '_' allowed
22,01 2_201     
22,02 2_202     
22,100 2_210     
22,101 2_211     
22,102 2_212     
22,110 2_220     
22,111 2_221     
22,112 2_222 <-- end of yours    
22,120 z0_0
```

That said, for a given number `x`, we can can count how many supercycles (`E(x / P)`) there are, each supercycle making two leading `e` (`e` being the last char of `A`).
e.g: `A = {0,1,2}` and `x = 43`

```
e = 2
P = n(n^{n-2} - 1)/(n-1) + n^n = 3(3^1 -1)/2 + 27 = 30
// our supercycle is of length 30
E(43/30) = 1 // 43 makes one supercycle and a few more "strings"
r = x % P = 13 // this is also x - (E(43/30) * 30) (the rest of the euclidean division by P)
```

Then for the left over (`r = x % P`) two cases to consider:

1. either we fall in the geometric sequence
2. either we fall in the `(n-1) * n^(n-1)` part.

#### 1. Adressing the geometric sequence with cumulative sums (`x < S_w`)

Let `S_i` be the cumsum of `n, n^2,..`

```
S_i = n\sum_{k = 0}^{i-1} n^k
S_i = n/(n-1)*(n^i - 1)
```

which gives `S_0 = 0, S_1 = n, S_2 = n + n^2...`

So basically, if `x < S_1`, we get `0(x)`, elif `x < S_2`, we get `1(x-S_1)`

Let `S_w = S_{n-1}` the count of all the numbers we can represent.

If `x <= S_w` then we want the `i` such that
`S_i < x <= S_{i+1} <=> n^i < (n-1)/n * x + 1 <= n^{i+1}`

We can then apply some log flooring (base(n)) to get that i.

We can then associate the string: `A[i] + base_n(x - S_i)`.

---

Illustration:

This time with `A = {0,1,2,3}`.

Let `x` be `17`.

Our consecutive `S_i` are:

```
S_0 = 0
S_1 = 4
S_2 = S_1 + 4^2 = 20
S_3 = S_2 + 4^3 = 84
S_w = S_{4-1} = S_3 = 84
```

`x=17` is indeed less than `84`, we will be able to affect it to one of the `S_i` ranges.
In particular `S_1==4 < x==17 <= S_2==20`.

We remove the strings encoded by the leading 0(there are a number `S_1` of those strings).

The position to encode with the leading 1 is 
`x - 4 = 13`.

And we conclude the thirteen's string generated with a leading 1 is `base_4(13) = '31'` (idem string -> `'131'`)

Should we have had `x = 21`, we would have removed the count of `S_2` so `21-20 = 1`, which in turn gives with a leading 2 the string `'2001'`.

#### 2. Adressing x in the special part (`x >= S_w`)

Let's consider study case below:

with `A = {0,1,2}`
The special part is

`2 |1| |2|^2`
that is:

```
2 0 00
2 0 01
2 0 02
2 0 10
2 0 11
2 0 12
2 0 20
2 0 21
2 0 22

2 1 20
2 1 21
2 1 22
2 1 10
2 1 11
2 1 12
2 1 20
2 1 21
2 1 22
```

Each incremented number of the second column (here `0` to `1` (specified from `|1|`)) gives `3^2` combination.

This is similar to the geometric series except that here each range is constant. We want to find the range which means we know which string to prefix.

We can represent it as the matrix

```
20 (00,01,02,10,11,12,20,21,22)
21 (00,01,02,10,11,12,20,21,22)
```

The portion in parenthesis is our matrix.

Every item in a row is simply its position base_3 (left-padded with 0).

e.g: `n=7` has base_3 value '21'. (`7=2*3+1`).
'21' does occur in position `7` in the row.

Assuming we get some `x` (relative to that special part).

- `E(x / 3^2)` gives us the row number (here `E(7/9) = 0` so prefix is '20')
- `x % 3^2` give us the position in the row (here `base_3(7%9)='21'` giving us the final string `'2021'`)

If we want to observe it remember that we substracted `S_w=12` before to get `x = 7`, so we would call `myGen(7+12)`

---

#### Some code

- Notice the same output as long as we stand in the "geometric" range, without supercycle.
- Obviously, when carry starts to appear, it depends on whether I can use '_' or not. If yes, my words get shorter otherwise longer.

```js
// https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/zju/math/int-alg.html
// \w insensitive could give base64
// but also éè and other accents...
function base_n(x, n, A) {
  const a = []
  while (x !== 0n) {
    a.push(A[Number(x % n)])
    x = x / n // auto floor with bigInt
  }
  return a.reverse().join('')
}

function mygen (A) {
  const n = A.length
  const bn = BigInt(n)

  const A_last = A[A.length-1]
  const S = Array(n).fill(0).map((x, i) => bn * (bn ** BigInt(i) - 1n) / (bn - 1n))
  const S_w = S[n-1]

  const w = S_w + (bn - 1n) * bn ** (bn - 1n)
  const w2 = bn ** (bn - 1n)
  const flog_bn = x => {
    // https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627914/smart-way-to-calculate-floorlogx
    let L = 0
    while (x >= bn) {
      L++
      x /= bn
    }
    return L
  }
  return function (x) {

    x = BigInt(x)
    let r = x % w
    const q = (x - r) / w
    let s
    if (r < S_w) {
      const i = flog_bn(r * (bn - 1n) / bn + 1n)
      const r2 = r - S[i]
      s = A[i] + base_n(r2, bn, A).padStart(i+1, '0')
    } else {
      const n2 = r - S_w
      const r2 = n2 % w2
      const q2 = (n2 - r2 ) / w2
      s = A_last + A[q2] + base_n(r2, bn, A).padStart(n-1, '0')
    }
    // comma below __not__ necessary, just to ease seeing cycles
    return A_last.repeat(2*Number(q)) +','+ s 
  }
}

function genStr (A) {
  A = A.filter(x => x !== '_')
  const bn_noUnderscore = BigInt(A.length)
  return function (x) {
    x = BigInt(x);
    let prefix = "",
        cycle = 0n,
        max = bn_noUnderscore ** (cycle + 1n);
    while (x >= max) {
      x -= max;
      if (cycle === bn_noUnderscore - 1n) {
        prefix += "z";
        cycle = 0n;
      } else {
        cycle++;
      }
      max = bn_noUnderscore ** (cycle + 1n);
    }
    return prefix
           + base_n(cycle, bn_noUnderscore, A)
           + "_"
           + base_n(x, bn_noUnderscore, A).padStart(Number(cycle) + 1, 0);    
  }
}
function test(a, b, x){
  console.log(a(x), b(x))
}
{
  console.log('---my supercycle is shorter if underscore not used. Plenty of room for grandinero')
  const A = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b))
  let my = mygen(A)
  const grandinero = genStr(A)
  test(my, grandinero, 1e4)
  test(my, grandinero, 1e12)
  test(my, grandinero, 106471793335560744271846581685593263893929893610517909620n) // cycle ended for me (w variable value)
}
{
  console.log('---\n my supercycle is greater if underscore is used in my alphabet (not grandinero since "forbidden')
  // underscore used
  const A = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_'.split('').sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b))
  let my = mygen(A)
  const grandinero = genStr(A)
  test(my, grandinero, 1e12)
  test(my, grandinero, 106471793335560744271846581685593263893929893610517909620n) // cycle ended for me (w variable value)
  test(my, grandinero, 1e57) // still got some place in the supercycle
}
```

Comment: I must admit I don't understand all of your math, but this is definitely an improvement on my effort. Thanks!

Comment: absence of tex does not help to make it clear, and "formulas" appear a bit ugly. If you tell me which part is not clear, I can clarify/develop with examples. Also if you want to minimize the math part, notice than when the number lies in the geometric sequence, you can apply your algorithm instead! @grandinero

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that I don't understand much after "the supercycle is of length:". In the codeblock after that phrase, I think that you are using the formula to calculate the sum of a geometric series, but I get a different result. For an alphabet of 36 characters expanding from a length of 1 to 36, I get `36*((1-36**36)/(1-36)) === 1.094e+56`. Your equation seems to be `((36*(36**34-1))/35)+(36**36) === 1.065e+56`. When I plug the former value into my `genStr`, I get `z0_0`, indicating that it is the correct breakpoint for the supercycle. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are not missing anything and you are right. If you replace n by 36 into P you do get the length of my supercycle: ```((36*(36**34-1))/35)+(36**36)``` (which you can verify by injecting that number which should give zz,00). The only improvement comes if you can use the ```_``` char which allows you to replace 36 by 37. I will try to illustrate/develop more after the codeblock

Comment: I have edited my post to give examples with numerical values so hopefully the part after the codeblock is more understandable @grandinero. Do not hesitate to ask for clarification

Answer (score 1):

After considering the advice provided by @kaya3 and @grodzi and reviewing my original code, I have made some improvements.  I realized a few things:

1. There was a bug in my original code.  If one cycle ends at `z_z` (actually 36 z's after the underscore, but you get the idea) and the next one begins at `z0_0`, then lexical ordering is broken because `_` comes after `0`. The separator (or "neck") needs to be lower in lexical order than the lowest possible value of the head.
2. Though I was initially resistant to the idea of rolling a custom baseN generator so that more characters can be included, I have now come around to the idea.
3. I can squeeze more permutations out of a given string length by also incrementing the neck. For example, I can go from `A00...A0z` to `A10...A1z`, and so on, thus increasing the number of unique strings I can generate with `A` as the head before I move on to `B`.

With that in mind, I have revised my code:

```js
// this is the alphabet used in standard baseN conversions:

let baseAlpha = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

// this is a factory for creating a new string generator:

function sequenceGenerator (config) {
  let 
      // alphabets for the head, neck and body:

      headAlpha = config.headAlpha,
      neckAlpha = config.neckAlpha,
      bodyAlpha = config.bodyAlpha,

      // length of the body alphabet corresponds to the
      // base of the numbering system:

      base = BigInt(bodyAlpha.length),

      // if bodyAlpha is identical to an alphabet that
      // would be used for a standard baseN conversion,
      // then use the built-in method, which should be
      // much faster:

      convertBody = baseAlpha.startsWith(bodyAlpha)
                    ? (n) => n.toString(bodyAlpha.length)

      // otherwise, roll a custom baseN generator:

                    : function (n) {
                        let s = "";
                        while (n > 0n) {
                          let i = n % base;
                          s = bodyAlpha[i] + s;
                          n = n / base;
                        }
                        return s;
                      },

      // n is used to cache the last iteration and is
      // incremented each time you call `getNext`
      
      // it can optionally be initialized to a value other
      // than 0:

      n = BigInt(config.start || 0),

      // see below:

      headCycles = [0n],
      cycleLength = 0n;
      
  // the length of the body increases by 1 each time the
  // head increments, meaning that the total number of
  // permutations increases geometrically for each
  // character in headAlpha

  // here we cache the maximum number of permutations for
  // each length of the body
    
  // since we know these values ahead of time, calculating
  // them in advance saves time when we generate a new
  // string
    
  // more importantly, it saves us from having to do a
  // reverse calculation involving Math.log, which requires
  // converting BigInts to Numbers, which breaks the
  // program on larger numbers:

  for (let i = 0; i < headAlpha.length; i++) {

    // the maximum number of permutations depends on both
    // the string length (i + 1) and the number of
    // characters in neckAlpha, since the string length
    // remains the same while the neck increments

    cycleLength += BigInt(neckAlpha.length) * base ** BigInt(i + 1);
    headCycles.push(cycleLength);
  }

  // given a number n, this function searches through
  // headCycles to find where the total number of
  // permutations exceeds n
  
  // this is how we avoid the reverse calculation with
  // Math.log to determine which head cycle we are on for
  // a given permutation:

  function getHeadCycle (n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < headCycles.length; i++) {
      if (headCycles[i] > n) return i;
    }
  }

  return {

    cycleLength: cycleLength,

    getString: function (n) {
      let cyclesDone = Number(n / cycleLength),
          headLast = headAlpha[headAlpha.length - 1],
          prefix = headLast.repeat(cyclesDone),
          nn = n % cycleLength,
          headCycle = getHeadCycle(nn),
          head = headAlpha[headCycle - 1],
          nnn = nn - headCycles[headCycle - 1],
          neckCycleLength = BigInt(bodyAlpha.length) ** BigInt(headCycle),
          neckCycle = nnn / neckCycleLength,
          neck = neckAlpha[Number(neckCycle)],
          body = convertBody(nnn % neckCycleLength);
      body = body.padStart(headCycle , bodyAlpha[0]);
      return prefix + head + neck + body;
    },

    getNext: function () { return this.getString(n++); }

  };
}

let bodyAlpha = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    getStr = sequenceGenerator({

      // achieve more permutations within a supercycle
      // with a larger headAlpha:

      headAlpha: "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",

      // the highest value of neckAlpha must be lower than
      // the lowest value of headAlpha:

      neckAlpha: "0",
      bodyAlpha: bodyAlpha
    });

console.log("---supercycle length:");
console.log(Number(getStr.cycleLength));
console.log("---first two values:")
console.log(getStr.getNext());
console.log(getStr.getNext());
console.log("---arbitrary large value (1e57):");
console.log(getStr.getString(BigInt(1e57)));
console.log("");

// here we use a shorter headAlpha and longer neckAlpha
// to shorten the maximum length of the body, but this also
// decreases the number of permutations in the supercycle:

getStr = sequenceGenerator({
  headAlpha: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  neckAlpha: "0123456789",
  bodyAlpha: bodyAlpha
});

console.log("---supercycle length:");
console.log(Number(getStr.cycleLength));
console.log("---first two values:");
console.log(getStr.getNext());
console.log(getStr.getNext());
console.log("---arbitrary large value (1e57):");
console.log(getStr.getString(BigInt(1e57)));
```

---

EDIT

After further discussion with @grodzi, I have made some more improvements:

1. I realized that the "neck" or separator wasn't providing much value, so I have gotten rid of it. **Later edit**: *actually, the separator is necessary. I am not sure why I thought it wasn't. Without the separator, the beginning of each new supercycle will lexically precede the end of the previous supercycle. I haven't changed my code below, but anyone using this code should include a separator. I have also realized that I was wrong to use an underscore as the separator. The separator must be a character, such as the hyphen, which lexically precedes the lowest digit used in the sequence (0).*
2. I have taken @grodzi's suggestion to allow the length of the tail to continue growing indefinitely.

Here is the new code:

```js
let baseAlpha = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

function sequenceGenerator (config) {

  let headAlpha = config.headAlpha,
      tailAlpha = config.tailAlpha,
      base = BigInt(tailAlpha.length),
      convertTail = baseAlpha.startsWith(tailAlpha)
                    ? (n) => n.toString(tailAlpha.length)
                    : function (n) {
                        if (n === 0n) return "0";
                        let s = "";
                        while (n > 0n) {
                          let i = n % base;
                          s = tailAlpha[i] + s;
                          n = n / base;
                        }
                        return s;
                      },
      n = BigInt(config.start || 0);

  return {

    getString: function (n) {
      let cyclesDone = 0n,
          headCycle = 0n,
          initLength = 0n,
          accum = 0n;
      for (;; headCycle++) {
        let _accum = accum + base ** (headCycle + 1n + initLength);
        if (_accum > n) {
          n -= accum;
          break;
        } else if (Number(headCycle) === headAlpha.length - 1) {
          cyclesDone++;
          initLength += BigInt(headAlpha.length);
          headCycle = -1n;
        }
        accum = _accum;
      }
      let headLast = headAlpha[headAlpha.length - 1],
          prefix = headLast.repeat(Number(cyclesDone)),
          head = headAlpha[Number(headCycle)],
          tail = convertTail(n),
          tailLength = Number(headCycle + initLength);
      tail = tail.padStart(tailLength, tailAlpha[0]);
      return prefix + head + tail;
    },

    getNext: function () { return this.getString(n++); }

  };
}

let alpha = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    genStr = sequenceGenerator({headAlpha: alpha, tailAlpha: alpha});

console.log("--- first string:");
console.log(genStr.getString(0n));
console.log("--- 1e+57");
console.log(genStr.getString(BigInt(1e+57)));
console.log("--- end of first supercycle:");
console.log(genStr.getString(63n*(1n-(63n**63n))/(1n-63n)-1n));
console.log("--- start of second supercycle:");
console.log(genStr.getString(63n*(1n-(63n**63n))/(1n-63n)));
```

Comment: I think your supercycle is still less than mine (with alphabet [0-9a-zA-Z_], i get about 2.10e114). An other idea: up to this point we have considered a constant super cycle. What may (or not) be of interest is to increase the supercycle length by incrementing the number of digits allowed in tail (so after say 1 supercycle done, and 64 tail length, we allow 65 tail length and so forth) which in case of very very big (...) number would lower the head length and thus the overall string length while not increasing significantly the "average" string length

Comment: Actually, if I'm not mistaken, I think you get about 2.28e+113 when you use that alphabet. The example I gave above actually uses a smaller alphabet in the head because it is not including "0" or "_", but if I use the same size alphabet as yours in both the head and body, I get 2.32e+113. I'm a bit confused by what happens at the end of your supercycle. It seems like it ends at "zyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" and the next cycle starts at "zz00". Why doesn't it go to "zz00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"?

Comment: because I wanted compact strings if possible, but yes you can improve it that way. Regarding the count, you are right I wrongly copied the decimal part and counted the whole string length forgetting the comma...

Comment: But those two strings are the same length. `zy` + 62 `z`s should be followed by `zz` + 62 `0`s, and then the cycle should continue from there until you get to 64 consecutive `z`s, which should be the end of the first supercycle. The reason your supercycle is a bit shorter than mine is because yours ends prematurely. There might be an error in one of your calculations. BTW, I also like your suggestion of continuing to 65 tail length and so on. That is a very good idea and I will include it in my final version.